# Make ubi filesystem image from directories

Tags: filesystems, embedded

I have a **rootfs** directory which contains all the directory structure (**bin**  **boot**  **dev**  **etc**  **home** ... **var**) to be installed on an embedded board .

What I would like to accomplish, is to make a ubi image of the entire **rootfs** content, and then install this ubi image with u-boot on my embedded board.

I've executed these two commands:

```
sudo mkfs.ubifs -m 2048 -e 129024 -c 852 -r rootfs/ rootfs.img
sudo ubinize -o rootfs.ubi -p 131072 -m 2048 -s 512 -O 512 rootfs.img
```

But ubinize always returns this error:

```
iniparser: input line too long in rootfs.img (1)
ubinize: error!: cannot load the input ini file "rootfs.img
```

How can I make my ubi image of directory structure ?

Answer (score 2):

new a ini file "**ubinize.cfg**" :

```
[ubifs]
mode=ubi
image=rootfs.img
vol_id=0
vol_size=100MiB
vol_type=dynamic
vol_name=rootfs
vol_flags=autoresize
```

The ubinize.cfg file should be in ***unix*** format. Also make sure that there is ***an empty line*** at the end of the file.

run:

```
sudo ubinize -o rootfs.ubi -p 131072 -m 2048 -s 512 -O 512 ubinize.cfg
```

Comment: Welcome on the Unix SE! Your first line is incomprehensible, please fix it.